# can we add image through img tag in C#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

i want to add image through img tag in C#.net
i tried the following logic but it's not work

String img+="img src="abc.jpg"

if you know plz reply me

Comment: Where do you want to add image? where is an image tag in your code?

Comment: string img ?? i dont thing its possible dear !!

Comment: is it asp.net ..so want to add for ur website ??

Comment: Are you trying to add image dynamically to a page?

Comment: maybe he want to use response.write or add it in some control in this case it is possible :)

Comment: -1 Unclear question, You haven't supplied the environment you want the image to appear? eg Windows form app, asp.net, windows app that outputs html...

Answer (score 3):

In markup:

```
<asp:image id="myImage" runat="server" />
```

In code-behind:

```
myImage.ImageUrl = "abc.jpg";
```

Comment: This is an <asp:Image> not a <img>

Comment: @Carlos, <asp:Image> generates <img> in the generated HTML. It offers more options in ASP.NET, but in terms of generated output, it accomplishes the same goal.

Comment: @Cyclon Cat: Yes I know but the question was about "img tag" therefore my answer is about it.

Answer (score 3):

In .aspx

```
<img id="image" runat="server" />
```

In code behind

```
image.Src = "abc.jpg";
```

[More on HtmlImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlimage.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in .aspx page:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"  ImageUrl=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats how normlly we do for html!!!

```
<img src="flower01.jpg" alt="Yellow Flower" width="150" height="100">
```

for asp
we do

```
  <asp:Image ID="imgMain" runat="server"  ImageUrl="http://www.xyz.com/files/images/15%20Random%20Greenery.JPG"/>
```

can be done like this